# Animate+Smoothly interpolate between matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have a matrix of points like:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

originalPoints = np.asarray([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8,10,12]])
newPoints = np.asarray([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8,10,12]]) + 20
plt.scatter(originalPoints[0,:],originalPoints[1,:], color='red');
plt.scatter(newPoints[0,:],newPoints[1,:], color='blue');
```

And that gives me:

[image]

I am trying to generate a gif/animation showing the points moving along some smooth path from red to blue. I have been trying to use something like [what is discussed here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/drawing-animated-gifs-with-matplotlib/) and scipy's [interpolate discussed here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be great.

Bonus: a solution that would work in 3D as well

EDIT: To be clear, what I would like is some nonlinear smooth path along which each blue point moves to reach the red points. Note - the example above is made up. In reality there are just a bunch of blue points and a bunch of red points. Think about animating between two different scatter plots.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean 'showing the points moving along some smooth path from red to blue."? What isn't working?

Comment: Moreover, where would add a dimension?

Comment: @PrestonH I added an edit above.

Comment: @fuglede - The extra dimension would be in the points themselves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just create the linear path between each of the pairs of points; combining that with [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) would look like

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_plot(t):
    interpolation = originalPoints*(1-t) + newPoints*t
    scat.set_offsets(interpolation.T)
    return scat,

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.scatter(originalPoints[0,:],originalPoints[1,:], color='red')
plt.scatter(newPoints[0,:],newPoints[1,:], color='blue')
scat = plt.scatter([], [], color='green')
animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=np.arange(0, 1, 0.01))
```

[image: Linear path between points]

Edit: The edited question now asks for a non-linear interpolation instead; replacing `update_plot` with

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, 3, (2, 6))
def update_plot(t):
    interpolation = originalPoints*(1-t) + newPoints*t + t*(1-t)*noise
    scat.set_offsets(interpolation.T)
    return scat,
```

you get instead

[image: Nonsensical path between points]

Edit #2: Regarding the query on interpolation of colors in the comment below, you can handle that through [`matplotlib.collections.Collection.set_color`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection.set_color); concretely, replacing the above `update_plot` with

```
def update_plot(t):
    interpolation = originalPoints*(1-t) + newPoints*t + t*(1-t)*noise
    scat.set_offsets(interpolation.T)
    scat.set_color([1-t, 0, t, 1])
    return scat,
```

we end up with

[image: Interpolation with colors]

Regarding the "bonus": The 3D case is mostly similar;

```
a = np.random.multivariate_normal([-3, -3, -3], np.identity(3), 20)
b = np.random.multivariate_normal([3, 3, 3], np.identity(3), 20)

def update_plot(t):
    interpolation = a*(1-t) + b*t
    scat._offsets3d = interpolation.T
    scat._facecolor3d = [1-t, 0, t, 1]
    return scat,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 2], c='r')
ax.scatter(b[:, 0], b[:, 1], b[:, 2], c='b')
scat = ax.scatter([], [], [])
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=np.arange(0, 1, 0.01))
ani.save('3d.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
```

[image: 3D example]

Edit regarding the comment below on how to do this in stages: One can achieve this by incorporating [the composition of paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition) directly in `update_plot`:

```
a = np.random.multivariate_normal([-3, -3, -3], np.identity(3), 20)
b = np.random.multivariate_normal([3, 3, 3], np.identity(3), 20)
c = np.random.multivariate_normal([-3, 0, 3], np.identity(3), 20)

def update_plot(t):
    if t < 0.5:
        interpolation = (1-2*t)*a + 2*t*b
        scat._facecolor3d = [1-2*t, 0, 2*t, 1]
    else:
        interpolation = (2-2*t)*b + (2*t-1)*c
        scat._facecolor3d = [0, 2*t-1, 2-2*t, 1]
    scat._offsets3d = interpolation.T
    return scat,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 2], c='r')
ax.scatter(b[:, 0], b[:, 1], b[:, 2], c='b')
ax.scatter(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c='g')
scat = ax.scatter([], [], [])
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=np.arange(0, 1, 0.01))
ani.save('3d.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
```

[image: Example using path composition]

Comment: thanks @fuglede! Can you post your full working code? Also, I meant more like - along some *curve*, like a spline or something

Comment: Linear paths are both curves and splines. Also, outside of a `.save('scatterplots.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')`, this is in fact the full working code.

Comment: Hm. Ok well thank you I'll play around with that you've given me - last question - In order for me to interpolate the color as well, I'd have to create a corresponding color map?

Comment: Also, can you call this in a for loop/stages? So that the green first goes towards the blue, and then to wards a nother set of points, etc.?

Comment: For the first one: no; I've added an example on how to go interpolate between red and blue colors. For the second question, I would simply modify `update_plot` accordingly, checking the value of `t`.

Comment: thank you you've been a big help I really appreciate it